# Sharing sass files between an npm package and a ruby gem

Tags: javascript, ruby, npm, sass, rubygems

I have two libraries where I am creating view components. One library is written in sass for styles and typescript for markup. The other is using ruby for the markup (view helpers) and also using sass for the stylsheets.

I want to share the sass between both frameworks. The gem is a rails engine so it has this directory structure:

```
-app
--assets
---stylesheets
----engine_name
-----button.scss
```

the npm package is something like

```
-src
--components
---button.scss
```

How could these two codebases cleanly share `button.scss` I don't mind having both the gem and npm package in the same repo and accessing a common directory but how do you import sass files in a rails engine if the files are not actually at `app/assets/**`